# [RESOLVED ]Problem with an old version of // Jquery Help upgrade to last version

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar

I have problem with a code after migrating to jquery 3

NOT WORKING : Need update and need delete ui jquery
**I would like migrate to 3.6 but error :**
https://jsfiddle.net/alex447/u817ybjk/1/

Working but old version :
https://jsfiddle.net/alex447/c06tb5rL/28/

Having done very little jquery I would like to review the code in the latest jquery version and without ui-query so that the progress bar is displayed.

If you change the code to version `1.5` with ui jquery you can see the final result I want.

If i go to jquery 3.4.1 or other I have error :

> "jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).progressbar is not a function",
> "TypeError: $(...).progressbar is not a function
> at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/?editor_console=true:728:23)
> at mightThrow (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js:3534:29)
> at process (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js:3602:12)",
> undefined

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the [jQuery ui](https://code.jquery.com/ui/) library , ( knowing that progress()  function belong to this last ),

It works on the previous version because the is a checked input that import the ui automatically as you can see here :
[image]

add theme + jQuery ui cdn url will resolve the issue as this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/z3xkgmyd/)

But if you want to get rid of the jQuery ui ,

You could create your own progress , some css and simple js ,as shown in the below Snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("#progressbar").css("width",0);
    
    $('[type*=radio]').click(function() {
        var totalChecked = 0;
        var totalRadioGroups = 0;
        var previousName = '';
        $.each($('[type*=radio]'), function(index, value) {
            var radioName = $(this).attr('name');
            var radioId = this.id;
            
            if (previousName != radioName) {
                totalRadioGroups++;
            }
            if ($('#' + radioId).is(':checked')) {
                totalChecked++;
            }
            previousName = radioName;
        });
        var percentage = (totalChecked / totalRadioGroups) * 100;
        $('#progressbar').css('width', percentage+"%");
        $('#progressbar').html(percentage.toFixed(2) + "%");
        
        $('#percentage').html(percentage.toFixed(2) + "%");
    });

});
```

```css
#progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height:25px;
  border-radius:5px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#progressbar {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #0412AD;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  width:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Question 1<br>
<div class="js-form-item">
  <input type="radio" name="radioQone" id="radioQ11">Option 1<br>
</div>
<div class="js-form-item">
<input type="radio" name="radioQone" id="radioQ12">Option 2<br>
</div>
<div class="js-form-item">
<input type="radio" name="radioQone" id="radioQ13">Option 3<br>
</div>
<br>Question 2<br>
<div class="js-form-item79">
<input type="radio" name="radioQtwo" id="radioQ21">Option 1<br>
</div>
<div class="js-form-item78">
<input type="radio" name="radioQtwo" id="radioQ22">Option 2<br>
</div>
<div class="js-form-item34">
<input type="radio" name="radioQtwo" id="radioQ23">Option 3<br>
</div>
<br>Question 3<br>
<div class="js-form-item111">
<input type="radio" name="radioQthree" id="radioQ31">Option 1<br>
</div>
<div class="js-form-item11">
<input type="radio" name="radioQthree" id="radioQ32">Option 2<br>
</div>
<div class="js-form-item3">
<input type="radio" name="radioQthree" id="radioQ33">Option 3<br>
</div>

<br>Question 3<br>
<div class="js-form-item5">
<input type="radio" name="radioQFOUR" id="radioQ35">Option 1<br>
</div>
<div class="js-form-item-">
<input type="radio" name="radioQFOUR" id="radioQ36">Option 2<br>
</div>
<div class="js-form-itemè">
<input type="radio" name="radioQFOUR" id="radioQ37">Option 3<br>
</div>
<br>
<div id="progress-container">
  <div id="progressbar">
    
  </div>
</div>
<div id="percentage">
  <p>fff</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello but in localhost i have problem : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).progressbar is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js?qy2w85:35)
    at e (jquery.min.js?v=3.6.0:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js?v=3.6.0:2)                                    
              https://jsfiddle.net/alex447/u817ybjk/1/

Comment: New jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/alex447/u817ybjk/6/

Comment: try adding those after jquery js script : 
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` and 
`<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
`

Comment: Thank you!
do you think it is possible to do it without jquery ui? also?

Comment: @AlexSol its simple if you want no jQuery ui just look at my snippet on top , I've prposed a solution for you

Comment: You are great sorry I had not seen

Comment: You have idea for include select option beceause not working... Thanks ! i have try add :  $.each($('[type*=radio], [select*=option] '),  but not working thanks !

Comment: @AlexSol could you share the new code , or just create new question related to that issue !